# Why doesn't Microsoft Outlook fully support EML format, i.e. including email export?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, compatibility, file-format

EDIT: I am not asking HOW to save email from Outlook in EML format. Hence this question is **not a duplicate** of [How to save a mail into an .eml-file with Outlook?](https://superuser.com/q/75581/282786) !

I cannot find any relevant reference to the **missing full support for the EML format in Microsoft Outlook**, i.e. including export. (And yes, I *do* know that you can *open* an EML file in Outlook :) )

Is it a deliberate Microsoft decision, why you cannot save emails in the EML format? Or is it only "low priority"? Is it a remnant of the many Microsoft vendor lock-in attempts from the past? Has Microsoft ever made any statement about this missing interoperability function?

Comment: If you can open EML files, then support is not missing, is it?

Comment: @user1686 You cannot **export** an email from Outlook in EML format. It was in my question even before, but I modified it now so it is clearly visible even for speed readers :)

Comment: @harrymc No, I am not asking *how to* circumvent the missing feature, but if there are any public resources documenting why Microsoft decided not to support it out-of-the-box.

Comment: There aren't any published documents about internal decisions at Microsoft. They chose to support MSG, not EML, and all the rest is supposition.

Comment: Is this actually a question worth asking? If it's a deliberate decision, then what? If it's low priority, then what?

Comment: @gronostaj I was interested if there is any published statement about this decision. EML is a significant format and not supporting the export is not a small thing.

Answer (score -2):

According to your description, I have done a lot of search but I didn't find any Microsoft official documents introduced the related information. However, when saving and exporting email, we can find that only the following formats are supported:

**Save emails:**

[image]

**Export emails:**

.pst file / .csv file / .opml file

Therefore, it is not difficult to see that there is no one in it Options for EML. I don't think this needs to be tangled, just use the supported format.

Comment: it is not difficult to see that there is no one in it Options for EM, indeed!
This is just my original statement. That's exactly why I asked my question.